# Looping through API using jQuery each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the Marvel API to display a list of events a character has been involved in. Here is my script:

```
$(".heroSubmit").click(function() {

var heroName = $(".hero").val();


$.getJSON("http://gateway.marvel.com:80/v1/public/characters?name=" + heroName + "&apikey=", function (json) {
  $(".name").html(json.data.results[0].name);
  $(".description").html(json.data.results[0].description);
  $(".image").attr("src", json.data.results[0].thumbnail.path + "/detail.jpg");
  $(".comics").html(json.data.results[0].comics.available);

  $.each( json.data.results[0].events.items, function(i, item) {
    $(".events").html("<li>" + item.name + "</li>");
  });

});
```

Everything works fine except for the each section. Right now, it is only displaying the last event name (item.name). I need for all of the events to display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you rewrite events' content in each iteration. To avoid this replace `html()` with `append()`:

```
$.each( json.data.results[0].events.items, function(i, item) {
    $(".events").append("<li>" + item.name + "</li>");
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that would be a problem. Thanks for the help.